# mod_auth_sspi for wampserver 2.2

Tags: mod-auth

I have installed WAMPSERVER 2.2 for a intranet application.
Now I tried to get mod_auth_sspi to run to get a single-signon.
I downloaded the module from this link: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mod-auth-sspi/.
But it does not work.
WAMPSERVER does not start - the module is no Win32-Service says the error-log.

Can anyone give me a link which works?

Here some infos about the system:
WAMPSERVER 2.2-a -- 26/09/2011
VC9 Build
Passage à PHP 5.3.8
Passage à Apache 2.2.26
Passage à Mysql 5.5.16
Passage à PhpMyadmin 3.4.5
Passage à SQLBuddy 1.3.3
Passage à XDebug 2.1.2

Server is a Win 2008 R2.

Hope someone can help

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old, but I had the same issue. I found that the module was only 32 bit compatible. Someone converted it to x64. The link is listed below.

[x64 version](http://strawberryperl.com/package/kmx/mod_auth_sspi/x64/)

Answer (score 0):

The sspi module links a library to do ntlm.

The library is defined by the **SSPIPackage** instruction (see the doc file "installation" delivered with the module for more details).

I am not sure that Win2K8R2 is compliant with the sspi module (and vice versa) nor with 64b servers. But you can try to force the library used by the former instruction.